# Rows are not being added to SQL (ODBC connection)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, odbc

Everything seems to be ok, I see rows when I want to read from SQL, but when I'm adding them they do not appear in SQL Server (Yes I did refresh the database).
Here is my connection string:

```
connetionString = "Driver={Sql Server}; Server=baxu\\sqlexpress; Database = baza1;" + $"UID ={ username };PWD={ password };";
```

And here the code where I add rows:

```
cmdString = $"INSERT INTO {n} VALUES (?, ?);";
using (OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand())
{
    comm.Connection = connection;
    comm.CommandText = cmdString;
    comm.Parameters.Add("value", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int).Value = value;
    comm.Parameters.Add("time", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    rows += 1;
}
```

Comment: see if you have this "comm.Open();" also, you need to check that the ODBC Driver and the database version from the database are the same.
Check in DB
select @@version
Check ODBC
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Microsoft ODBC Source Administrator -> Drivers -> here check the column version of your database

Comment: Unrelated tip: Note that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected, so rather than `comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); rows+=1;`, do `rows+=comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Also, I'm assuming you have a good reason for using ODBC rather than just using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: @MEdwin *"see if you have this "comm.Open();""* - `comm` is an OdbcCommand - this does not have an `Open` method. I think you are confusing it with the `connection`, which is not shown.

Comment: Beware SQL injection attack, depending on where "n" comes from.

Answer (score 0):

@Ko Su, try this: I noticed that your definition of odbc connection variable and create command is the same.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

   class OdbcUpdate
   {
      static void Main()
      {

      OdbcConnection comm = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Sql Server}; Server=baxu\\sqlexpress; Database = baza1;" + $"UID ={ username };PWD={ password };"); 

      comm.Open();

      OdbcCommand myOdbcCommand = comm.CreateCommand();

      myOdbcCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)";

      myOdbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@field1", OdbcType.Int);
      myOdbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@field2", OdbcType.Int);

      myOdbcCommand.Parameters["@field1"].Value = 1;
      myOdbcCommand.Parameters["@field2"].Value = 2;

      Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Affected is: {0}", myOdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());

      comm.Close();

      Console.ReadKey();

      }
   }
```

Comment: *"I noticed that your definition of odbc connection variable and create command is the same"* - where are you seeing that? The question shows the creation of the command called `comm` but does not show the creation of the `connection` variable.

Comment: Other tips the `OdbcConnection` and `OdbcCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Also, you can just put the `.Value =` parts on the end of the `Parameters.Add` lines.